# @GrpcClient is null spring boot 3

Tags: java, spring, grpc

I am making grpc client using `net.devh.grpc-client-spring-boot-starter`

Client:

```
@Service
public class SystemService {
    @GrpcClient("handyman-client")
    StatusServiceGrpc.StatusServiceBlockingStub handymanClient;

    public VersionResponse getHandymanVersion() {
        return handymanClient.getVersion(Empty.newBuilder().build());
    }
}
```

application.yaml:

```
grpc:
  client:
    handyman-client:
      address: static://localhost:8080
      negotiationType: plaintext
```

In runtime `handymanClient` is `null`. Tried spring boot versions from `3.0.0` to `3.0.2`. Lowering the spring boot version to `2.7.0` solves the problem - the client is being created now.

Is there a workaround to make it work on spring boot 3?

build.gradle:

```js
plugins {
id 'java'
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.0'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.9.2"
}

group = 'hello.grpc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
compileOnly {
    extendsFrom annotationProcessor
}
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'

implementation group: 'net.devh', name: 'grpc-client-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.13.0.RELEASE'
implementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-stub', version: '1.53.0'
implementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-protobuf', version: '1.53.0'

}

sourceSets {
main {
    java {
        srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
        srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
    }
}
}

protobuf {
protoc {
    artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:4.0.0-rc-2'
}
plugins {
    grpc {
        artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.53.0'
    }
}
generateProtoTasks {
    all()*.plugins {
        grpc {}
    }
}
}

tasks.named('test') {
useJUnitPlatform()
}

springBoot {
buildInfo()
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter/issues/823) you must use the following configuration in your project :

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ImportAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ImportAutoConfiguration({
        net.devh.boot.grpc.client.autoconfigure.GrpcClientAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.client.autoconfigure.GrpcClientMetricAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.client.autoconfigure.GrpcClientHealthAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.client.autoconfigure.GrpcClientSecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.client.autoconfigure.GrpcClientTraceAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.client.autoconfigure.GrpcDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class,

        net.devh.boot.grpc.common.autoconfigure.GrpcCommonCodecAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.common.autoconfigure.GrpcCommonTraceAutoConfiguration.class,

        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcAdviceAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcHealthServiceAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcMetadataConsulConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcMetadataEurekaConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcMetadataNacosConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcMetadataZookeeperConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcReflectionServiceAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcServerAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcServerMetricAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcServerSecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        net.devh.boot.grpc.server.autoconfigure.GrpcServerTraceAutoConfiguration.class
})
public class GrpcConfig {
}
```

Comment: The issue has been removed. Not sure if it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Since autoconfiguration changed in springboot 3, META-INF/spring.factories was updated to META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports.
The update prevented grpc-client from autowiring.
On the latest master branch, the automatic assembly of springboot3 has been added. You can download the source code and compile and install it.

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yQ4z.jpg)